# Flag-handling dialog has odd line break

Tags: bug, design

Sorry, very minor issue.  The line break triggers my OCD.

> the flags have merit but no further action is … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …… required

[image: Screenshot of flag-handling popup]